# Selenium does not render html page source

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, webdriver, webdriverwait

I've tried to get data form a web page using python and selenium:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver=webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://covid19.min-saude.pt/ponto-de-situacao-atual-em-portugal/')
'RECUPERADOS' in driver.page_source
False
```

String 'RECUPERADOS' is present in browser window opened by driver, but not in page_source. What prevents selenium form rendering page html? Is there any way to get data from page like the one above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element text you are searching for is inside an `iframe`. You need to switch to iframe first and then wait for element to be visible and then capture the page_source.

Use `WebDriverWait`() and wait for `frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it`()

Use `WebDriverWait`() and wait for `visibility_of_element_located`()

```
driver.get('https://covid19.min-saude.pt/ponto-de-situacao-atual-em-portugal/')
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//*[@id='main']//iframe[1]")))
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//*[name()='text'][text()='RECUPERADOS']")))

if 'RECUPERADOS' in driver.page_source:
       print("YES")
else:
       print("NO")
```

Import below libraries.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

---

To jump out from `iframe` you need to use below code.

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```